# Prometheus node exporter capabilities and security context

Tags: kubernetes, security, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

### Question

What is the minimal security configuration of prometheus node exporter pods on Kubernetes ?

### Context

I have deployed the bitnami kube-prometheus-stack on my k8s cluster. The deployment was blocked due to some Kyverno policies that I enforce for security purpose:

- [disallow-capabilities-strict](https://kyverno.io/policies/pod-security/restricted/disallow-capabilities-strict/disallow-capabilities-strict/)
- [disallow-host-namespaces](https://kyverno.io/policies/pod-security/baseline/disallow-host-namespaces/disallow-host-namespaces/)
- [disallow-host-path](https://kyverno.io/policies/pod-security/baseline/disallow-host-path/disallow-host-path/)
- [disallow-privilege-escalation](https://kyverno.io/policies/pod-security/restricted/disallow-privilege-escalation/disallow-privilege-escalation/)
- [restrict-seccomp-strict](https://kyverno.io/policies/pod-security/restricted/restrict-seccomp-strict/restrict-seccomp-strict/)
- [restrict-volume-types](https://kyverno.io/policies/pod-security/restricted/restrict-volume-types/restrict-volume-types/)
- [disallow-host-ports](https://kyverno.io/policies/pod-security/baseline/disallow-host-ports/disallow-host-ports/)
- [disallow-host-ports-range](https://kyverno.io/policies/pod-security/baseline/disallow-host-ports-range/disallow-host-ports-range/)

I'm aware that the node-exporter need some privilege/caps but it's look a lot for me. Is someone know if some of this security parameters may be set without braking the operations of the node-exporter ?

### What already did ?

I already try to drop all capabilities of the node-exporter but it weren't able to work anymore...